# Multipart File Downloading in Spring?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, multipart

I'm developing an application to do some mp3 streaming from my server. I want the  user not to download the whole mp3 file, so the bytes are partially written in the OutputStream of the response.

I know this is also related to HTTP headers and ranges, so I found [this class](https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/d927d9b8cb9ea1268af74316cd20b7192ca92da7/src/main/java/lan/dk/podcastserver/utils/multipart/MultipartFileSender.java) that should work.

However, I'm using Spring MVC Controller and it seems to be not working as expected: the file is fully downloaded and there are two petitions to the Controller in one user request, with the following exception:

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

I know the existence of CommonsMultipartResolver, but all I found about this is for uploading files, not downloading. My question is, **is there something in Spring to do this easily?**

PD: I attach the code where I'm using the class mentioned above

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "merge/{name:.+\\.mp3}")
    public void playMerged( @PathVariable("name") String audioName, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
            String mergedAudioPath = service.getMergedAudio(audioName);
     MultipartFileSender.fromPath(Paths.get(mergedAudioPath)).with(request).with(response).serveResource();
   }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to break a content multipart is as follows:

```html
byte[] byteArray = null;

                        ByteArrayInputStream content = new ByteArrayInputStream(/*YOU BYTE[] RESPONSE*/);

                        MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(content, ("MIME_boundary").getBytes(), null);

                        boolean nextPart;
                        try {
                            nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();

                            while (nextPart) {
                                String header = multipartStream.readHeaders(); //HEADER MENSSAGE

                                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                multipartStream.readBodyData(byteArrayOutputStream); //Reads file within multipart

                                byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                                nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        retorno = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);

                        return retorno;
```